# AutoComplete showing suggestions not based on start of word

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

[image]

It is suggesting `Reunion` and `Tunisia` on top because they have the `uni` bit.

Desired behavior:

It should suggest based on start of word. I.e., `United Arab Emirates` should be displayed on top, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the documentation on [customising the filter function](https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#custom-filter).

```js
const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
  matchFrom: 'start',
});

<Autocomplete filterOptions={filterOptions} />;
```